# sort and slice on array inside a document

Tags: meteor

My doc:

```
"_id" : "bf63XML4bo6CrfP9A",
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "fzkhiAArD4mgAAjbL",
            "comment" : "what the hell are you doing in there?",
            "commentedAt" : 1422367883366
        }, 
        {
            "user" : "fzkhiAArD4mgAAjbL",
            "comment" : "tada tada",
            "commentedAt" : 1422368379037
        }, 
        {
            "user" : "fzkhiAArD4mgAAjbL",
            "comment" : "la la la la la",
            "commentedAt" : 1422368393536
        }, 
        {
            "user" : "fzkhiAArD4mgAAjbL",
            "comment" : "no no no",
            "commentedAt" : 1422368409692
        }
    ],
    "feed_id" : "ym8To4cdwwTcSczkS",
```

I want to send the recent 3 comments from this doc, how to do it?

I tried different things, nothing working

```
mycoll.find({_id:res._id},{fields:{sort: {commentedAt: 1}},fields: {comments:{$slice: 3}}});
```

**FYO**

I want this in publish funciton.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot sort the comments and then slice them, only slice them.  If you really need to sort and slice, you should probably use a [transform](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find), although I think this would be computationally more expensive.

However, if you've $pushed comments onto the array chronologically you should be able to do (on the server only):

```
mycoll.find({_id:res._id},{fields: {comments:{$slice: -3}}});
```

to get the last 3.